# Summing over ellipsis broadcast dimension in numpy.einsum

Tags: python, numpy

In numpy, I have an array that can be either 2-D or 3-D, and I would like to reduce it to 2-D while squaring each element. So I tried this and it doesn't work:

```
A = np.random.rand(5, 3, 3)
np.einsum('...ij,...ij->ij', A, A)
```

It returns this error:

```
ValueError: output has more dimensions than subscripts given in einstein sum, but no '...' ellipsis provided to broadcast the extra dimensions.
```

I suppose einsum doesn't assume that when the ellipsis goes away in the right hand side, I want to sum over the ellipsis dimension(s), if they exist. Is there some "elegant" way (i.e. without checking the number of dimensions and using an if statement) to tell it that I want to do this for 3-D:

```
A = np.random.rand(5, 3, 3)
np.einsum('aij,aij->ij', A, A)
```

and this for 2-D?

```
A = np.random.rand(3, 3)
np.einsum('ij,ij->ij', A, A)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes the 'elegant' way to handle variable dimensions is to use a set of `if` tests, and hide them in a function call.  Look for example at `np.atleast_3d`; it has a 4way if/else clause.  I'd recommend it here, except it adds the extra dimension at the end, not the start.  `if` clauses using `reshape` are not expensive (time wise), so don't be afraid to use them.  Even if you find some magical function, look at its code; you may be surprised what is hidden.

---

ellipsis is used for dimensions that 'go along for the ride', not ones where you want specific control.  Here you want to sum over the initial dimension, so you need to index it explicitly:

```
In [161]: np.einsum('i...,i...',A,A)
Out[161]: 
array([[ 1.26942035,  1.32052776,  1.74118617],
       [ 1.59679765,  1.49331565,  2.04573002],
       [ 2.29027005,  1.48351522,  1.36679208]])
In [162]: np.einsum('aij,aij->ij',A,A)
Out[162]: 
array([[ 1.26942035,  1.32052776,  1.74118617],
       [ 1.59679765,  1.49331565,  2.04573002],
       [ 2.29027005,  1.48351522,  1.36679208]])
```

For 2d array:

```
In [165]: np.einsum('ij,ij->ij',A[0],A[0])
Out[165]: 
array([[ 0.20497776,  0.11632197,  0.65396968],
       [ 0.0529767 ,  0.24723351,  0.27559647],
       [ 0.62806525,  0.33081124,  0.57070406]])
In [166]: A[0]*A[0]
Out[166]: 
array([[ 0.20497776,  0.11632197,  0.65396968],
       [ 0.0529767 ,  0.24723351,  0.27559647],
       [ 0.62806525,  0.33081124,  0.57070406]])
In [167]: 
In [167]: np.einsum('...,...',A[0],A[0])
Out[167]: 
array([[ 0.20497776,  0.11632197,  0.65396968],
       [ 0.0529767 ,  0.24723351,  0.27559647],
       [ 0.62806525,  0.33081124,  0.57070406]])
```

I don't think you can handle both cases with one expression.

Another way to get the first sum

```
In [168]: (A*A).sum(axis=0)
Out[168]: 
array([[ 1.26942035,  1.32052776,  1.74118617],
       [ 1.59679765,  1.49331565,  2.04573002],
       [ 2.29027005,  1.48351522,  1.36679208]])
```

I contributed the patch that fixed the handling of ellipsis, but that was a couple of years ago.  So the details aren't super fresh in my mind.  As part of that I reverse engineered the parsing the string expression (the original is compiled), and could review that code (or refer you to it), if we need a more definitive answer.

---

```
In [172]: np.einsum('...ij,...ij->ij',A,A)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-172-dfe39e268402> in <module>()
----> 1 np.einsum('...ij,...ij->ij',A,A)

ValueError: output has more dimensions than subscripts given in 
 einstein sum, but no '...' ellipsis provided to broadcast 
 the extra dimensions.
In [173]: np.einsum('...ij,...ij->...ij',A,A).shape
Out[173]: (5, 3, 3)
```

The error message says that it is trying to pass the `...` dimensions to the output, and can't - because the output is missing dimensions or `...`.  In other words, it does not perform summation over `...` dimensions.  They pass to the output unchanged (broadcasting rules apply).

Comment: Thanks, I do plan on just using an if statement, I was just curious about this case because the einsum function is quite interesting in that it is a declarative way to do array operations, and doesn't exist in many other array libraries/languages. I found that you brought up this case a while ago when you were reverse-engineering einsum in https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2455 (point 2). I wonder how much interest there would be in extending einsum to handle this case, as well as, for example, optional dimensions with labels that can be summed. Probably difficult to optimize though.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long way from being an elegant answer and literally years after the fact, but in case it helps others I've found the following approach to be a reasonable workaround which avoids explicit if statements for the number of dimensions. The basic idea is that you use a long enough string of arbitrary dimension names and then just use as many of those as you need each time:

```
# "Long enough" string of arbitrary dimensions
dims_str = 'abcdefg'

# 3D case
A = np.random.rand(5, 3, 3)
answer_A = np.einsum('aij,aij->ij', A, A) # Canonical version given in question
answer_B = np.einsum('{0:s}ij,{0:s}ij->ij'.format(dims_str[:A.ndim-2]), A, A) # "Hacked" solution
print(np.array_equal(answer_A,answer_B))

# 2D case
A = np.random.rand(3, 3)
answer_A = np.einsum('ij,ij->ij', A, A) # Canonical version given in question
answer_B = np.einsum('{0:s}ij,{0:s}ij->ij'.format(dims_str[:A.ndim-2]), A, A) # "Hacked" solution
print(np.array_equal(answer_A,answer_B))

# 4D case, why not
A = np.random.rand(6, 5, 3, 3)
answer_A = np.einsum('abij,abij->ij', A, A) # Canonical version given in question
answer_B = np.einsum('{0:s}ij,{0:s}ij->ij'.format(dims_str[:A.ndim-2]), A, A) # "Hacked" solution
print(np.array_equal(answer_A,answer_B))
```

When tested, it gave `True` for all three cases.